# Action Listener not being called in JSF2-Primefaces3 application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I am trying to get Latitude and Longitude in my JSF-2/Primefaces-3 application. I am using following code:

**XHTML**

```
<h:inputText id="address" value="#{nyBean.address}" />
<p:remoteCommand name="rmtCommandGeocoder" actionListener="#{myBean.getCordinates}" />
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
function geocoder() {
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
   geocoder.geocode({
      'address' : address
   }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         // Calls the remoteCommand "rmtCommandGeocoder",
         // passing the coordinates to map of parameters
         rmtCommandGeocoder([ {
            name : 'latitude',
            value : results[0].geometry.location.lat()
         }, {
            name : 'longitude',
            value : results[0].geometry.location.lng()
         }]);
      }
   });
}
```

**BEAN**

```
public void getCordinates() {
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   Map<String, String> parameterMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
   double latitude = Double.parseDouble((String) parameterMap.get("latitude"));
   double longitude = Double.parseDouble((String) parameterMap.get("longitude"));
}
```

The problem here is getCordinates() is not getting called. Any clue guys?

Answer (score 2):

change the signature into

```
public void retriveCordinates(ActionEvent event){
```

or just change from `actionListener` into `action`

Also

best practice would to use `get` or `set` prefix only for getter/setter , thats why I changed `getCordinates` into `retriveCordinates`